# Cast javascript object to array. How to?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made this sandbox test:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>whatever</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function myLittleTest() {
                var obj, arr, armap;

                arr = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11];

                obj = {};
                obj = arr;
                alert (typeof arr);
                alert (typeof obj);

                // doesn't work in IE
                armap = obj.map(function (x) { return x * x; });
                alert (typeof armap);

            }
            myLittleTest();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

I realize I can use jQuery's function $.map for making that line of code work, but, what am I missing on javascript datatypes?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish.  Do you want an array where each index represents a property from and object?  Or an object where each property represents a value from the array?

Comment: You're always going to get `object` from `typeof` for arrays.  Arrays are just objects with numeric properties, a few extra methods, and a magic `length` property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this isn't a type problem, it's because IE didn't have the `Array.map()` function until IE 9.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4h76zbx(v=VS.85).aspx for a list of supported functions.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff679976(v=VS.94).aspx for a description of the `Array.map()` function in IE 9.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4esdbwz(v=VS.94).aspx clearly states that the `Array.map()` function was introduced in IE 9.

Answer (score 61):

### Modern Answer

If you have an iterable, you can use the spread operator.

```
var a = [...o];
```

If you have an array-like object, (like `arguments`, for example,) you can get a real array made from it by calling [`Array.from(o)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

```
var o = {0:"a", 1:'b', length:2};
var a = Array.from(o);
```

`a` will be `["a", "b"]`. This will only work right if you have a correctly set `length` property.

---

### Older Answer

If you have an array-like object, (like `arguments`, for example,) you can get a real array made from it by calling `Array.prototype.slice.call(o)`.

```
var o = {0:"a", 1:'b', length:2};
var a = Array.prototype.slice.call(o);
```

`a` will be `["a", "b"]`. This will only work right if you have a correctly set `length` property.

Comment: +1 - This is also a great way to make a copy of the `arguments` array, since `arguments.slice()` doesn't work on `arguments`... and `= arguments` isn't helpful. http://jsfiddle.net/SMayA/

Comment: A shorthand for this would be `[].slice.call()`. This is something I learned from expressjs framework.

Comment: It's a bit wasteful though, creating a new Array everytime you need to call a method from its prototype?

Comment: Will the resulting array consist only of elements that qualify for `myobject.hasOwnProperty(mykey)` ?

Comment: @ThorSummoner: I don't think so, but I think it will only copy numeric properties. If you're inheriting numeric properties from your prototype, you're too clever, I think.

Answer (score 25):

I think you are trying too hard...

It's easiest with jQuery (or similar library)

For this object:

```
var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
```

Arrays have a fixed key system so for the object above, you've got to throw away either the keys (a, b, c) or the values (1, 2, 3)

So either this:

```
var arr = $.map(obj, function (value, key) { return value; });
```

or this:

```
var arr = $.map(obj, function (value, key) { return key; });
```

Comment: This method will remove null "properties". In my case i need the array count and item collection to be exactly equal

Answer (score 7):

A year ago now, but I may as well  mention jQuery's makeArray function http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/

Comment: `var t = {f: 4, h: 5};
var u = $.makeArray(t);`

u will be an array with one element: object t. I doubt that's what's needed here?

Comment: Wow, Janis, you're right. What the heck is the point of that? Why not just say [t]?!?

Comment: Janis, I took some time to realize this working with the debugger… You are dam' right.

Answer (score 5):

Use a `for` loop for max browser compatibility.

In Javascript all arrays are objects, but not all object are arrays. Take a look at **[this Perfection Kills page](http://perfectionkills.com/instanceof-considered-harmful-or-how-to-write-a-robust-isarray/)** which describes how to check that something is an Array.

To check for an array, you can use `Object.prototype.toString.call(theObject)`. This will return `[object Array]` for an object that is an Array and `[object Object]` for an object that's not an Array (see example below):

```
            function myLittleTest() 
            {
                var obj, arr, armap, i;    

                  // arr is an object and an array
                arr = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11]; 

                obj = {}; // obj is only an object... not an array

                alert (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj));
                  // ^ Output: [object Object]

                obj = arr; // obj is now an array and an object

                alert (Object.prototype.toString.call(arr));
                alert (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj));
                  // ^ Output for both: [object Array]

                // works in IE
                armap = [];
                for(i = 0; i < obj.length; ++i)
                {
                    armap.push(obj[i] * obj[i]);
                }

                alert (armap.join(", ")); 

            }
            // Changed from prueba();
            myLittleTest();
```

### **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Jn5z6/)**

Answer (score 2):

Among many other small utilities for manipulating objects and arrays, Underscore.js offers a `toArray(obj)` helper method. Documentation here: http://underscorejs.org/#toArray

It's not totally obvious from the way the documentation is written, but it works like a charm on arbitrary objects. When given an object, it iterates over the values and returns a list that contains just those values.