# How to retrieve random JSON object by key from JSON dictionary?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, random, iterator

I have a JSON object which consists of a long list of other JSON objects which have some common properties to each other such :

```
var myData = { 
    "0291" : { "Firstname" : "Jeremy", "Surname" : "Dyson" },
    "0398" : { "Firstnname" : "Billy", "Surname" : "Bunter" },
    "6714" : { "Firstnname" : "Harry", "Surname" : "Peterson" },
    "9080" : { "Firstnname" : "Barry", "secondname": "Joe", "Surname" : "Mainwaring"}
    ...
    ...
}
```

I already built an html template. With the JS, I want to pick or iterate (random pick + loop) through the objects in data{} in **random order**, so I can fill up the HTML on the fly for each visitor. The random part is important, so each visitor likely get a different data.

Plain JavaScript or jQuery solutions will work in the context in which this is being deployed.

---

**EDIT:** Solution I implemented is below.

**1. Collect all keys :**

```
var keyArray = Object.keys(myData);
```

**2. [Shuffle function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array-in-javascript/6274381#6274381):**

```
function shuffle(o){ //v1.0
    for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
    return o;
};
keyArray = shuffle(keyArray); // shuffle it!
```

**3. Loop to iterate:**

```
for (var i = 0; i < keyArray.length; ++i) {
    var current = data[keyArray[i]];
    ... // what you want to do each time.
}
```

Comment: What is generating the JSON?  Seems like it would be easier to randomize it at that point

Comment: @explosion: I start coding, I write the 4000 lines lexical database by hand. No random function... yet !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, convert the `data` object to an array (the keys on the first level will be lost), like shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11474071/664108

```
var dataArray = $.map(data, function (value, key) { return value; });
```

Then shuffle the array (see [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-a-javascript-array))

Alternatively you could just shuffle the keys and then operate on the original object. This way you also have still the keys:

```
var keyArray = $.map(data, function (value, key) { return key; });

shuffle(keyArray); // example (shuffle function has to be implemented, see above)

for (var i = 0; i < keyArray.length; ++i) {
    var current = data[keyArray[i]];
    // do stuff with current dataset
}
```

**Addition from the comments**

the key array can also be created by:

```
var keyArray = Object.keys(data);
```

But note that this only works on modern browsers, you should not use it if you want to support Internet Explorer in versions up to IE 8 (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff688127(v=vs.94).aspx)

Comment: I think I will need the keys. Indeed, I now need to grasp again my data > a random key > to pick the values I want.

Comment: rather than :
var keyArray = $.map(data, function (value, key) { return key; });

Let's use :
 var keyArray = Object.keys(data);

Comment: I voted your answer up, but accepted my answer which I implemented in my code. (note: I get no point from accepting my own answer.)

Answer (score 3):

Have you think about generating the JSON randomly already or shufflng it? [Shuffle in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array-in-javascript)

If you shuffle the array, you can apply foreach and you get the items in a random order. :)

Note: It might be faster to shuffle just a copy of the IDs.

Disclaimer! I asuumed that for your case you need just [Pseudorandomness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandomness).

Comment: Mario, thanks again. Your comments were really adapted to the begginner I am, I was looking for a **shuffle** function indeed.

Answer (score 0):

use the Object.keys function

```
var obj = { 0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c' };
console.log(Object.keys(obj)); // console: ['0', '1', '2']
```

more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys