# Mustache.js: large JSON dictionary & smaller know list of entries to display randomly onfly?

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js, mustache

I just started to use mustache.js, I have my json dictionary, my html template, and my mustache.js startup code to inject the whole. My html-mustache template is such:

```
<script id="tpl" type="text/html">
    <div class="body">
        <p>{{口.zht}}</p>
        <p>{{口.sam.pyn}}</p>
        <p>{{口.sam.fra}}</p>
    </div>
</script>
```

In my test case with a given existing entry '口', it works ([1](http://jsfiddle.net/hugolpz/jKQUM/6/)). But I notice that Mustache seems designed to iterate **all** the JSON entries. However, I want to work on a small focusList of entries

```
var focusList = ['們','火山口','火'];
```

for which I want to pick the corresponding data from my larger (~1000 entries) JSON dictionary.

**How can I change or make variable {{#口}} and {{/口}} according to my focusList, so I may print my template with the correct data?**

Is there some kinds of variables in the template such:

```
<script id="tpl" type="text/html">
    <div class="body">
        <p>{{{{entry}}.zht}}</p>
        <p>{{{{entry}}.sam.pyn}}</p>
        <p>{{{{entry}}.sam.fra}}</p>
    </div>
</script>
```

and in the JS I add:

```
var entry = focusList[Math.floor(Math.random() * focusList.length)]]
```

?

Comment: Can you slice out the piece you want before Mustache sees anything? The usual approach with Mustache is to do all the data massaging before Mustache sees the data.

Comment: I'am a PhD linguist doing a proof of concept in JS/HTML/CSS. I can't process the JSON dictionary with other languages, sadly. Should I create a partial copy of the dictionary using focusList = ['們','火山口','火'], and then ask mustach.js to process this miniDictionary ? JS indications/keywords please.

Comment: Yes, a partial copy of the data would be the usual Mustache way. You could also check a few other template engines (http://garann.github.com/template-chooser/), they all have their pros and cons of course.

Comment: I understand better. Thanks Mu.

Comment: There is a way! insane, out of mustache, but working.

Comment: Solution posted below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution: given a small list of keys, mustache-print relevant entries from larger JSON data:**

```
//1. Suggest a smaller custom list of keys existing in the larger data. 2. Randomize.
var focusList = ['們','火山口','火'];
var randomKey = focusList[Math.floor(Math.random() * focusList.length)];
//3. variable + Template + variable. 4. printing.
var template = ('{{#'+ randomKey +'}}'+ $('#tpl').html() +'{{/'+randomKey+'}}'); // as {{#火}} ... {{/火}}
var output = Mustache.render(template, myBigJSON);
$('#main').append(output)
```

**Alternatively 1:** you can also get the whole list of entries using Object.keys ([2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)) to **print a random entry from the WHOLE list:**

```
//1. Get and create the list of all keys
var focusList = Object.keys(myBigJSON);
```

**Last,** rather than randomize and loop which may repeat some entries, you may **[shuffle the given list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array-in-javascript/6274381#6274381) and [iterate the shuffled list systematically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697371/how-to-retrieve-random-json-object-by-key-from-json-dictionary#14697612) to print each item systematically.**