# What is causing “Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o” with $.parseJSON() and JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I Have looked all over SO and Google but have have noting that has helped and I'm unsure how to continue. I have an array which I am returning from a php page using `echo json_encode()` that looks like this:

```
[" "," "," "," "," ",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31]
```

but I keep getting `Unexpected token o at Object.parse (native)` when I try to use JSON.parse() and `Unexpected token o at Function.parse (native)` when I use the JQuery alternitive.

but when I just attach it to the `$scope` I can print it out using on the page, so What am I doing wrong and how can I correct this?

this is my controller

```
function myController($scope, memberFactory) {

    response = memberFactory.getMonth("2013-08-01 06:30:00");
    //$scope.response = response;
    var monthDays = $.parseJSON(response);

    var dates = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < monthDays.length; i++) {
        if (i % 7 == 0) dates.push([]);
        dates[dates.length - 1].push(monthDays[i]);
    }
    $scope.dates = dates;
    //
}
```

this is my Service Method:

```
obj.getMonth = function (date) {
    var month = $q.defer();
    $http.get('getMonth.php?date=' + date)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        month.resolve(data);

    });

    return month.promise;
}
```

and this is my php:

```
<?php $daysOfMonth=[ " ", " ", " ", " ", " ",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31];
echo json_encode($daysOfMonth); ?>
```

### Things I have Tried

If I return the `typeof` I get Object, so I have then tried `var monthDays  = Array.prototype.slice.call(response)` and `var monthDays  = $.map(response, function (value, key) { return value; });`as suggested in some of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865139/cast-javascript-object-to-array-how-to), I have also tried `JSON.stringify()` but I just get `{}` as the result

I am really frustrated with this an really need someone to point me in the correct direction

### Update

I believe this may be an issue with using `$q.defer()` as I updated my getMonth Method as follows:

```
obj.getMonth = function (date) {
    var month = $q.defer();
    $http.get('getMonth.php?date=' + date)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        month.resolve(data);
        console.log("data " + data[0]);
        console.log("resolved " + month.promise[0]);

    });

    return month.promise;
}
```

now I get `1` for `console.log("data " + data[0]);` as expected but I get for `console.log(month);` I get `[object Object]` for`console.log(month.promise)` I get `[object Object]`and for `console.log(month.promise[0]);` I get `undefined`

Comment: What do you see in the debugger?

Comment: @Slak I just see [object object]

Comment: There could be invisible characters like BOM.. also don't mix types in an array.

Comment: @Esailija no invisible Characters, and mixing types isn't the issue as I tried with just numbers and just strings, get the same issue

Comment: The advice about mixing types wasn't related to your immediate problem but a general advice

Answer (score 65, accepted):

`response` is already parsed, you don't need to parse it again.

If you parse it again it will perform a toString-cast first so you're parsing

```
"[object Object]"
```

which explains the `unexpected token o`.

Comment: So how do I access the values, I tried using response[0] but no luck, I tried `Object.keys(response)` to get the keys, it returns `then` and response["then"] returns nothing

Comment: Do `console.log(response);` to see what it looks like. `response[0]` should work if you're getting that Array back.

Comment: for `console.log(response)` I get  `[object Object]` , for  `console.log(response[0])` I get undefined , If I attach to scope like this `$scope.response = response` then `{{response}}` appears as `["","","","","",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31]`

Comment: That doesn't look right at all .. can you verify that you've not got a 2nd hidden parse somewhere?

Comment: no 2nd parse, I've removed them all

Answer (score 6):

Please take a look a the chapter *Transforming Requests and Responses* of the [$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) module.

> If JSON response is detected, deserialize it using a JSON parser.

Since it is already parsed as JSON object, if you parse it again, you will get that error.

Here is a simple test:

```
response = '{"a": "a","b": "b"}';
var obj = $.parseJSON(response);
console.log(obj); //Object {a: "a", b: "b"} 
$.parseJSON(obj)  //Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
```

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved with help of @CuongLe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143800/why-is-the-result-of-defered-promise-after-defered-resolvemyobject-not-the-sam) by replacing

```
 response = memberFactory.getMonth("2013-08-01 06:30:00");
 var monthDays = $.parseJSON(response);
```

with:

```
response = memberFactory.getMonth("2013-08-01 06:30:00");
response.then(

function (monthDays) {
    console.log("monthDays : " + monthDays + " !!!");

    var dates = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < monthDays.length; i++) {
        if (i % 7 == 0) dates.push([]);
        dates[dates.length - 1].push(monthDays[i]);
    }

    $scope.dates = dates;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If the header is sent:

```
Content-Type: text/json
```

Then `parseJSON()` does not need to be called. For example:

In a PHP I would set the header like this:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/json");
echo json_encode(array("someKey" => "someValue"));
```

And in Javascript I would have something like this for the success function:

```
success: function(response) {
// This will output "someValue" to the console.
// Note the lack of the parseJSON() call. parseJSON() is called for us because the header was sent as text/json
console.log(response.someKey);
}
```