# Getting 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token' trying to parse JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I'm getting an 'Uncaught SyntaxError' while trying to parse a JSON string, and I can't figure out why.

It looks like `message` is a string, which seems to be a common problem, and the json appears to be valid. A snippet of my code is given. It fails on the `var obj = ...` line.

```
this.send = function (message) {
    console.log(message);
    console.log(message.toString());
    console.log('{"ReadyToGo":1}');
    console.log(typeof message);
    var obj = $.parseJSON(message);
}
```

On the console, I get this just before the error.:

```
{"ReadyToGo":1}
{"ReadyToGo":1}
{"ReadyToGo":1}
string
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**: Added console.log(typeof message), which yields 'string'

Comment: Do `console.log(typeof message);`

Comment: What is the value of message when you pass it?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are doing this:  console.log('{"ReadyToGo":1}');

Comment: @Hrishi: He's doing it for the purpose of comparison to the other two `console.log()`s above it.

Comment: If message is indeed a string which is like this: '{"ReadyToGo":1}', then $.parseJSON(message) is returning a valid json object. Tried it in Chrome's console.

Comment: @Hrishi: Running this in Chrome (32.0.1700.76). I really can't explain this

Comment: Since you're getting `"string"` from `typeof message`, then the only thing I could guess would be that there's some invalid invisible character. What happens if you do `console.log(message === '{"ReadyToGo":1}');`?

Comment: [Refer this link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)for more information of parseJSON with jquery.And [json.org](http://www.json.org/) it will help you.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: {"ReadyToGo":"1"} try like this and do $.parseJSON(message);

Comment: just try JSON.parse(message);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130081/what-is-causing-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-o-with-parsejson-an suggests that your error message is incomplete -- jQuery provides the actual error character at detection.  What's the full error?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got this sorted. A null character ( '\0' ) was been appended to the string somewhere along the long call chain, and this wasn't visible in the debugger. Thanks to [cookie monster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3096782/cookie-monster) for the heads-up on this one.

Everything works as soon as I strip out the null char.