# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a web app I am working on:

```
$("#post").click(function () {

    var u = $('#u').val();
    var j = $('#j').val();

    $.post("http://www.myweb.php", {
            u: u,
            j: j
        })
        .done(function (data) {


            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            alert(obj.status );
            //alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
        });

});
```

When it tries to retrieve the JSON I get:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
```

Comment: So what's `data`...?

Comment: There is no syntax error in the code that you posted, it must be elsewhere, perhaps in the JSON data. [From the jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/): **Passing in a malformed JSON string results in a JavaScript exception being thrown**

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 the syntax error is coming from the JSON parser.

Comment: see this:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130081/what-is-causing-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-o-with-parsejson-an

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't have to call `.parseJSON()`. Your response has already been parsed. You're getting that error because the object you pass to `jQuery.parseJSON()` is being converted to the string `"[object Object]"`. The unexpected token is that "o" in "object".

Comment: so would I do data.status instead of obj.status if I take out the parse line?

Comment: @Mike yes, or just assign `data` to `obj`.