# How can i change the Json Data Format?

Tags: json

i have the following Json Data with following format...

```
var oData = [
{           
    "0":
    {
        "firstname": "aaa",
        "lastname": "zzz",
         "Email": "aaa@test.com"
    },

    "1":
    {
        "firstname": "bbb",
        "lastname": "yyy",
        "Email": "bbb@test.com"
    },

    "2":
    {
        "firstname": "ccc",
        "lastname": "www",
        "Email": "ccc@test.com"
    }

}];
```

Can we convert to the following format ??

```
var rData = [              
    {
        "firstname": "aaa",
        "lastname": "zzz",
        "Email": "aaa@test.com"
    },

    {
        "firstname": "bbb",
        "lastname": "yyy",
        "Email": "bbb@test.com"
    },

    {
        "firstname": "ccc",
        "lastname": "www",
        "Email": "ccc@test.com"
    }];
```

Comment: You can convert a Jobject (the first one) into a jArray but you are going to have to read it out yourself and rebuld it.   There is no way that i know of to automaticly convert them.

Comment: Sort of a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865139/cast-javascript-object-to-array-how-to

Comment: By using which programming language you want to convert it?

Comment: The answer to your question is "yes".  But is that all you really wanted to know?

Comment: Since you haven't specified a language you'll have to use a text editor and do it manaually...

Answer (score 1):

```
    var oData = [{           
        "0":
        {
            "firstname": "aaa",
            "lastname": "zzz",
             "Email": "aaa@test.com"
        },

        "1":
        {
            "firstname": "bbb",
            "lastname": "yyy",
            "Email": "bbb@test.com"
        },

        "2":
        {
            "firstname": "ccc",
            "lastname": "www",
            "Email": "ccc@test.com"
        }

    }],
    data = oData[0],
    rData = [];
JSON.stringify( data, function( key, value ) {
    rData.push( value );
});
console.log( rData );
```