# Get array count in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this:

```
elements = {
    opinions: ['p31/php/endpoint.php?get=opinions'], // function to call and API endpoint, php/endpoint.php
    top3positive: ['p31/php/endpoint.php?get=top3positive'], // function to call andAPI endpoint, php/endpoint.php
    top3negative: ['p31/php/endpoint.php?get=top3negative'], // function to call andAPI endpoint, php/endpoint.php
};
```

How do I point to the 1 first array. If I do `alert(elements[0]);` it is not returning opinions as I would expect.
What am I doing wrong?

I need to point to the array index based on its order 0,1,2 etc.

Thanks

Comment: The `{}` notation is for objects, not arrays. You access `opinions` by doing `elements.opinions`.

Comment: @whatyouhide   What if I need to access the index by number? How do I convert it in an array?

Comment: I posted an answer which explains the object/array confusion here.

Comment: This w3school webpage shows lots of examples of using arrays in javascript: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865139/cast-javascript-object-to-array-how-to

Answer (score 3):

The `{}` notation creates objects, not arrays. Hence, they are not integer-indexed and their properties have to be accessed using a classic dot notation or using `[]`.

If you want an array, this is the correct way to build it:

```
elements = [
    'p31/php/endpoint.php?get=opinions', // function to call and API endpoint, php/endpoint.php
    'p31/php/endpoint.php?get=top3positive', // function to call andAPI endpoint, php/endpoint.php
    'p31/php/endpoint.php?get=top3negative', // function to call andAPI endpoint, php/endpoint.php
];
```

If you leave your object as is in your question, you can access e.g. its first element like this:

```
elements.opinions;
```

or

```
elements['opinions'];
```

#### Micro-edit

I left a trailing comma in the array, which is fine in modern browsers but can cause some issues in older IEs. Just to be clear :)

Comment: <strike>Array don't have keys in JS. I mean you can add them, but that's abusing the data structure.</strike> (resolved)

Comment: OOOPS sorry sorry sorry, I forgot to remove them :)

Comment: Happens, just wanted to clarify :)

Comment: he needs to know how to convert the object to an array, not access the object like and array

Comment: @Brenden objects are not ordered collections, so he can't convert it into an array and be sure to access `opinions` when accessing `elements[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you set them as objects, you can access them as:

```
elements['opinions'];
elements['top3positive'];
elements['top3negative'];
```

If you want to set them as an array then:

```
var elements=['p31/php/endpoint.php?get=opinions','p31/php/endpoint.php?get=top3positive','p31/php/endpoint.php?get=top3negative'];
```

Then when you want to access to the item in array you can do:

```
elements[0];
```

Comment: Yes I understand this, but as I said I need to access them by index with a number. How do I convert this object into an array